# (Swift 5) Pass Variables from Function to Function

Tags: ios, swift, function, variables

I need to access a Variable from a function in a different function,
but Xcode is not showing me the variable in autofill.

I want to access the variables: `trinkgeldAnzeige`, `gesamtKostenAnzeige` and `kostenProPersonAnzeige` from `ausrechnenDerKosten` in `UIElementeAnzeigen`

Here is the code:

```
func ausrechnenDerKosten() {    
    if !(betragEingeben.text!.isEmpty) && !(personen.text!.isEmpty) {
        betrag = Double(betragEingeben.text!)!
        trinkgeldAnzeige = Double(prozentSlider.value)

        trinkgeldAnzeige = (betrag * trinkgeldAnzeige) / 100
        gesamtKostenAnzeige = betrag + trinkgeldAnzeige
        kostenProPersonAnzeige = gesamtKostenAnzeige / Double(personenAnzeige)

        UIElementeAnzeigen()      
    } else {
        anzeige(message: "Bitte Zahl Eingeben!")
    }
}
```

And I need to access the Variables here: `***Variable***(placeholder)`

```
func UIElementeAnzeigen() {
    let trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel = String(format: "%.2f", ***Variable***)
    let kostenProPersonAnzeigeLabel = String(format: "%.2f", ***Variable***)
    let gesamtKostenAnzeigeLabel = String(format: "%.2f", ***Variable***)

    trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel.text = "Trinkgeld: " + trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel + " euro"
    kostenProPersonAnzeigeLabel.text = "Trinkgeld: " + kostenProPersonAnzeigeLabel + " euro"
    gesamtKostenAnzeigeLabel.text = "Trinkgeld: " + gesamtKostenAnzeigeLabel + " euro"
}
```

but as I described, Xcode does not show me at the place where I wrote ***Variable*** to autofill the variable.

Comment: You can give the function some parameters so that you can pass in variables. Surely that has come up in the lecture?

Comment: Thx for the reply, but What kind of parameters? the tutor didnt specify any and it worked in his case.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], [tour].

Answer (score 2):

If `trinkgeldAnzeige`, `gesamtKostenAnzeige` and `kostenProPersonAnzeige` are properties you can directly access them in the method `UIElementeAnzeigen` as @vadian explained. You can tell if they are properties as you will have defined them outside of the function, something like this:

```
var trinkgeldAnzeige: Double = 0
var gesamtKostenAnzeige: Double = 0
var kostenProPersonAnzeige: Double = 0
```

Otherwise you would need to modify the declaration of `UIElementeAnzeigen` to take them as arguments:

```
func UIElementeAnzeigen(_ trinkgeldAnzeige: Double, _ gesamtKostenAnzeige: Double, _ kostenProPersonAnzeige: Double)
```

And you would call it with:

```
UIElementeAnzeigen(trinkgeldAnzeige, gesamtKostenAnzeige, kostenProPersonAnzeige)
```

If you do not add `_` before each variable in the function declaration you would call it with:

```
UIElementeAnzeigen(trinkgeldAnzeige: trinkgeldAnzeige, gesamtKostenAnzeige: gesamtKostenAnzeige, kostenProPersonAnzeige: kostenProPersonAnzeige)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the three variables are properties so you can use them directly in the update UI function. And your naming is ambiguous, I recommend to use different names for the formatted strings

```
func UIElementeAnzeigen() {

    let trinkgeld = String(format: "%.2f", trinkgeldAnzeige)
    let kostenProPerson = String(format: "%.2f", kostenProPersonAnzeige)
    let gesamtKosten = String(format: "%.2f", gesamtKostenAnzeige)

    trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel.text = "Trinkgeld: " + trinkgeld + " euro"
    kostenProPersonAnzeigeLabel.text = "Kosten pro Person: " + kostenProPerson + " euro"
    gesamtKostenAnzeigeLabel.text = "Gesamt: " + gesamtKosten + " euro"
}
```

Comment: Just Starting ;) thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Your `func UIElementeAnzeigen()` should be like this

```
    func UIElementeAnzeigen(trinkgeldAnzeige: Double, gesamtKostenAnzeige: Double, kostenProPersonAnzeige: Double) {
        let trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel = String(format: "%.2f", trinkgeldAnzeige)

        trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel.text = "Trinkgeld: " + trinkgeldAnzeigenLabel + " euro"

}
```

and you can call this function in your `func ausrechnenDerKosten()` like this:

```
UIElementeAnzeigen(trinkgeldAnzeige: trinkgeldAnzeige, gesamtKostenAnzeige: gesamtKostenAnzeige, kostenProPersonAnzeige: kostenProPersonAnzeige)
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: I will try it now, thx. will tell you if it worked.

Comment: This is incorrect: you can't call the method that way unless you add `_ ` before each variable name in the function declaration

Comment: This is additionally incorrect due to the fact that `String` is not the same as `Double`

Comment: @Wyetro, he can infer the types for what he's doing, Also _ is required for optional parameters. Better check swift documentation.

Keep it as simple as possible he's new that's what he mentioned

Comment: A beginner who doesn't know how pass variables to a function won't understand to infer the type. Also you misunderstand how function declarations work in Swift. Yours will throw the error `Missing argument label 'trinkgeldAnzeige': in call`

Comment: Thx to all for the help. I am doing my best to understand but i just started.

Comment: I updated mine, @Wyetro please remove your downvote

Comment: @SahilJaidka - done